# Reverse Geocoding using Python and Google API

Tags: python, api, google-maps, csv, pandas

I am trying to reverse geocode 500 lat and long random points using google API. I wrote the code below but I notice there are some errors that I need help with. I want to create a output CSV that has the Lat/Long and complete address of the reverse geocode and also the JSON geo_Data. Some of the errors is that my Ouput CSV is not being written and I don't know how to parse out just the address to my output CSV. Can anyone help me?

Script cited below:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests 

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/albertgonzalobautista/Desktop/Amsterdam_RP500_2.csv')

# create new columns
df['geocode_data'] = ''
df['address']=''

# function that handles the geocoding requests

def reverseGeocode(latlng):
    result = {}
    apikey = 'XXX'
    url = f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={latlng}&key={apikey}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    data = r.json()
    if data['results']:
        result = data['results'][0]
    return result

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    df['geocode_data'][i] = reverseGeocode(df['lat'][i].astype(str) + ',' + df['lon'][i].astype(str))


for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'address_components' in row['geocode_data']:
        for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:  

df.to_csv('testingGEO233.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code in this for loop

```
for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
```

maybe try this

```
for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
    df['address'] = row['geocode_data']['address_components']
```

You might actually want a string instead of a list of the components:

```
for component in row['geocode_data']['address_components']:
    df['address'] = row['geocode_data']['formatted_address']
```

Comment: What about the CSV writer. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: What's the error?  When I run it (with my changes) it outputs to csv just fine.  If you only want to output a single field, you can do something like `df['address'].to_csv`

Comment: Nevermind I got it working there where some minuscule errors when I was working on it. I am getting black fields though. Is that because I reached my limit or I am not doing it right?

Comment: It's tough to say without more information...but you can determine if you're over the limit by checking the `status` field.  If you are, it will be set to `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`  Pretty sure if you verify your identity you can increase the limit to something ridiculous like 25k/day instead of the default, which I think is 1k/day.

Comment: So I am still getting black data when running 500 responses to be geocoded but when I run smaller number it allows me. How can I fix this problem? Is it because I am not delaying my responses?